# removing a pattern entry from a inside a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

i got the query as if the given pattern exists in the file with the very next line starting and ending with the same pattern, delete the line that starts and ends with the given pattern

**input is like :**

```
abcd & abcd
& abcd &
abcd & abcd
& abcd
abcd abcd
& abcd &
abcd & abcd
abcd &
abcd & abcd
& abcd &"
```

**output to be :**

```
abcd & abcd
abcd & abcd
& abcd
abcd abcd
& abcd &
abcd & abcd
abcd &
abcd & abcd
```

and I used the sed command as

```
var=`sed -n "/$1/{n;p}" $2 | grep "^$1" | grep "$1$"`
sed -i "/^$var$/d" $2
```

but the command removes only the first pattern of the file

Comment: shouldn't `abcd abcd` be deleted also? and also `& abcd &`, since both start and end with the same pattern

Comment: only '& abcd &' has to be removed

Comment: it is not clear the pattern, could you give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: if we have a pattern '&' in the first line and if the next line starts and ends with the same pattern, then that line should be removed

Comment: and how do you determine which is the pattern to be checked from a given line?

Comment: is that quote on the last line a typo ?

Answer (score 0):

Sed

```
sed '/^\& abcd \&$/d' YourFile
```

Grep

```
grep -v '^& abcd &$' YourFile
```

Comment: I suspect this is far more complex, since the logic of a line has to do with the content of the previous one

Comment: right, i just take the sample but it's not representative. I will adapt.

Comment: too confuse, abort the challenge in sed due to recursive comparaison on each line by each other. Awk will do the trick. May be later when I have time.

Comment: I think this is a perfect case of a question that should be closed as "Unclear what you are asking", since also the OP is not clarifying.